# How to automatically log out if the user is idle for a certain period of time on yii2

Tags: yii2

I have given the task to introduce automatically logout feature in the webstie using Yii2 framework. I am new, please if anyone can guide me

Comment: add your config, this should be the default behavior but you need to add the config file

Answer (score 0):

You can set authTimeout property in user components config

```
'user' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\User',
    'authTimeout' => 3600
],
```

above code will automatically logout user after 1 hour.